# Use JavaScript in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I know JavaScript and asp.net but this is first time I am using JavaScript in asp.net . I face a little problem.

My problem is JS function `isvaliduser()` return true or false,all time '`cObj.Save(courseObj)`' is called ! I need when JS function return true only that time `cObj.Save(courseObj)` will call otherwise `cObj.Save(courseObj)` will not call.

This is my code :

```
 CGateway cObj = new CGateway ();
 protected void saveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     CInfo cInfoObj = new CInfo();
     cInfoObj.AName= ANameTextBox.Text;

     cObj.Save(courseObj);
 }
```

JavaScript :

```
function isvaliduser()
{
    var uid;
    var temp = document.getElementById("<%=ANameTextBox.ClientID %>");
    uid = temp.value;
    if(uid == "")
    {
       alert ("Please Enter UserName”);
       return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

ASPX:

```
<asp:Button ID="saveButton" runat="server" Text="Save"
OnClientClick ="javascript:isvaliduser()" />
```

How can I do it? Thank you.

Comment: I saw you asking about basic javascript in your previous question and someone did answer that (the same code in this question). And now [**that quesion**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23723897/use-javascript-in-asp-net) is deleted. So, my point is, you should have requested for clarification right under his answer instead of deleting that question.

Comment: Because my that id become blocked. y? I don't know. Thats why I ask this question. clear @Raging Bull ?

Comment: What you mean by blocked? See the old question link in my previous comment. It says: `voluntarily removed by its author`.

Answer (score 3):

You need the OnClientClick to return true or false (which if true will submit the button and if false will not). Something like this should work:

```
<asp:Button ID="saveButton" 
    runat="server" 
    Text="Save" 
    OnClientClick="return isvaliduser();" />
```